# Recurring Invoices using API

Tags: square-connect

I am a developer trying to setup a recurring invoice automatically from code.  I am using .NET using C#.  What I want to do is create the recurring invoice when they check out behind the scenes without me having me to manually create one from the Square dashboard.  Is there a way to call the API and do it programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

You can not send invoices via API at this time.

Comment: My users are subscribing to a monthly subscription for some magazines.  When they checkout, they should know right away that it is a subscription.  Is there any solution you can think of that could accomplish this?

Comment: Sure, just keep their card on file and tell them very clearly in the UI that they will be billed monthly.

Comment: Is it possible to use the API to retrieve invoice data?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see anything for directly scheduling Square's Invoices.

Howerver, until they add that functionality, you could put together something to a similar effect.

You can use C# .NET to hit Square's Webbased Rest API.

For the API reference you can checkout
https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2/#swaggerspecification

As far as doing it from C#, you can achieve HTTP actions using the HttpClient Class
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.110).aspx

A good chunk of stuff that you can do from a web browser, can be done with HTTP Requests and a little be of digging into some of the HTML you are trying to automate.